# Connecting Laravel to SQL Server: [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I am trying to connect Laravel (install via forge to ubuntu) to a SQL Server.

From the server I **can** connect to the database using the command:

```
forge@server:/etc/php/8.1/fpm$ sqlcmd -S HOST\\INSTANCENAME -U USER -P PASSWORD -C
```

My error comes when I then try to connect in to Laravel:

**database.php**

```
'bp_database' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('BP_DB_HOST'),
            'port' => env('BP_DB_PORT'),
            'database' => env('BP_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('BP_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('BP_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'trust_server_certificate' => true,
],
```

**.ENV**

```
BP_DB_CONNECTION=bp_database
BP_DB_HOST=HOST
BP_DB_PORT=1433 
BP_DB_DATABASE=INSTANCENAME 
BP_DB_USERNAME=USER
BP_DB_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
```

**TestController.php**

```
 public function testBPDatabase()
    {
        
        try {
            DB::connection('bp_database')->getPdo();
            dd('connected');
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd("Could not connect to the database.  Please check your configuration. error:" . $e );
        }
        
    }
```

So to recap:

- My test controller works correctly when I use a default mySql connections
- It does not work when I test 'bp_database'
- It does connect to this db from command line
- I have had someone check my .env cred are correct.

The error I am receiving is:

> error:PDOException: SQLSTATE[HYT00]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired in /home/forge/default/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70

---

**FUTHER EDIT:**
A few days later and still can figure this out.
I have tried removing Laravel from the picture and (mostly) following the Microsoft instruction for connecting with php [Microsft SQL server connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-php?view=sql-server-ver16) and [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php). I still get the exact same error.

DB Connection code

```
   $serverName = "172.36.100.2\\BPSINSTANCE";
   $connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"bpsrawdata", "PWD"=>"password");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

   if( $conn ) {
       echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
       var_dump( sqlsrv_errors());
       die();
    }
```

There error I am getting know (pretty much the same as the laravel one)

```
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired
```

then further down the error stack:

```
Error Locating Server/Instance Specified
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server is not MySQL. Have you actually configured a Microsoft SQL Server to listen on port 3306, or are you actually trying to connect to a MySQL server using the SQL Server driver? Note: the port number for the default `MSSQLSERVER` instance is typically 1433.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning `sqlcmd` is a SQL Server-specific utility, and it's stated that using this works, so I'd guess OP has perhaps copied some MySQL settings in the PHP and forgotten to change the port to 1433.

Comment: @ADyson TRUE! you are correct. I had forgotten to set the port. It is now set to 1433 (and I confirmed this is the correct port for my specific connection). 
Unfortuantly though I am still getting the same error.

Comment: It's strange, then. Did you specify all the settings like host etc precisely the same way in the PHP settings as in the sqlcmd?

Comment: Now I'm not so sure I did. I didn't realize the named instance was different to the database name. I belive my gaps in knowledge of SQL Server are showing now. I will edit my question, but where I have written `DBNAME` in the command I have learnt is actually the instance name no the database name. Unsure how to declare this properly in Laravel.